# How to add columns to existing table

Tags: database, addition, alter

I am very new to SQL coding, I am using SQL Developer as the software to code.
I have a question, which I have tried to google and figure out but am having trouble.
I create a table called patvisit (patient visit) from two datasets Patient and visit. So I run the code below to create the new table patvisit. However, how do I add new columns with values into patvisit table without dropping the table and rerunning it. For example, I run the code below and create the table patvisit after I make the table I forget that I also wanted to add address that was in the patient table. Now what I would do is drop the patvisit table and then re-run the below code and add another column a.address. But is there a way to use the ALTER or ADD rules to be able to add a new column to an existing table? I tried looking for example codes online but I don't seem to get it. would appreciate any assistance/advise.

create table pativisit as
select distinct a.patientId, b.visit_no, b.visit_code, a.admit_date, a.discharge_date
from Patient a
inner join visit b
on a.visit_no=b.visit_no;

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link on using the `SQL ALTER TABLE`statement to ad a column:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp